# Key receiving though my application is not in focus?

Tags: android

I have a doubt in android. Consider am having two applications namely A and B. Suppose application B has been launched from application A. As of now, B is in focus and will receive all key events. is it possible to receive the keys in a common place irrespective the application being focused ( A or B ).

Is it possible for my application to know which key the user has presently pressed though my application is not in focus ?

Plz advise me as soon as possible..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to receive the keys in a common place irrespective the application being focused ( A or B )

No, sorry. This would be a very large security hole.